# Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. when use react-router-hash-link in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

When i use react-router-hash-link in next js it's show me the error in bellow, please send me the perfect solution thanks

Comment: The component where you're trying to use this is not wrapper in <Router>.

Comment: I know but next js file-system based routing working

Comment: You shouldn't use React Router, Next.js provides its own built-in router.